# Can't link user to their corresponding results CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

i have a page that shows all student profiles with their results. all the user info i putted in the table "user"
and then i have another table "results" that shows all the students their scores from diffrent courses. the thing is i don't know how to write the query or controller function to link the student with their corresponding results. I need some help here thanks

Controller

```
        function students()  
        {  
            $data = array(); 
            $this->load->model('kdg_model');
            $query = $this->kdg_model->get_students();
            $query2 = $this->kdg_model->get_resultStudent();
                if ($query)
                {
                    $data['user'] = $query;
                    $data['results'] = $query2;
                }

                $this->load->view('students_view',$data);

        }
```

Model

get_students get all rows from the database table user.
get_resultstudent gets all the rows from results. tried to combine them but it just gives me all the same rows back on every profile.

```
         function get_students(){
            $this->db->where('admin', 0);
            $query = $this->db->get('user');  
            return $query->result();
         }
         function get_resultStudent(){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('results');
            $this->db->join('user', 'user.id_user = results.FK_student');
            $query = $this->db->get(); 
            return $query->result();
         }
```

Comment: codeigniter not codeignitor lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your database schema looks like but from what I can work out I've got this.  Okay so in your controller you want to build your array of students.  Let do this by calling two model functions.  The first model function we are going to call we get us all of the students in the 'user' table.  The model will pass back an array to the controller which we can loop through to get the individual students.  On each iteration of the loop we can pass the 'id_user' to another function in our model to get the results for that student.

```
//This is where we will store the students and their results
$aData['aStudentResults'] = array(); 

//Load the model we need
$this->load->model('kdg_model');

//Get an array of students
$aStudents = $this->kdg_model->get_students();

//Now we have an array of student id's let loop through these and for each student
//let get their results
foreach($aStudents as $student)
{
    //Add the student to the array
    //The student id (id_user) is the key
    $aData['aStudentResults'][$student->id_user] = $this->kdg_model->get_resultStudent($student->id_user);
}

//Pass out array of students to the view
$this->load->view('students_view', $aData);
```

These are the model functions we are calling in the controller

```
//Get all the students that are not admins
function get_students(){
    $this->select('id_user')
        -from('user')
        ->where('admin', 0);
    $query = $this->db->get();  
    return $query->result();
}

//Use the id_user we were passed by the controller to get the results
function get_resultStudent($id_user){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('results');
    $this->db->where('FK_student', $id_user);
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

At this point we now have all the data we need.  We just need to pass it from the controlle to the view which we did by passing the view $aData.  In our view we can access what we passed to it like so

```
<? foreach($aStudentResults as $studentId => $aResults): ?>
    <p>Student id: <?= $studentId ?></p>

    <?foreach($aResults as $aResult): ?>
        //Do something with results
    <? endforeach; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

This hasn't been tested so there may be some syntax errors but hopefully you should get an idea of what I am trying to do and what you need to do.

It's important for you to understand how MVC works.  Practice selected data from your database in your models, and then passing that data to your views via the controller.  You'll quickly get the hang of it.

If there is anything you don't understand in this answer please leave a comment and let me know.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, now there are a few things when you call get_resultStudent() shouldn't be there an argument between the () Also when you load the view isn't it the $adata that i have to set as variable?

Comment: @user2696666 Yep, my bad, changed

Comment: @user2696666 No you don't reference $aData in the view.  If you pass $aData['value1'] you would just use $value1 in the view

Comment: if i wanna output, like the students name how can i do this?

Comment: Still when you run it. it says Undefined variable: aStudentResults

Comment: got any answer for this i would like to show some student sinformation but i only got the id now from user

Comment: @user2696666 First you would need to select it from the database and store it in the array

Comment: Can i do this by adding $aData['aStudentInfo'] = array(); and after that $aData['aStudentinfo'][$student->id_user] = $this->kdg_model->get_studentInfo($student->id_user); in the same loop as i filled in the aStudentResults?